# Are there statistics on people answering their own questions right away?

Tags: discussion

Since we just had it recently brought up again about people answering their own questions immediately, I thought it would be useful to have statistics of how the self-answered questions stack up against the other questions where that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there are [292 self-answered questions on the site](http://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/784836/self-answered-questions-on-a-site) out of 3960 for 7.37% of all questions.

There are [116 self-answered questions where the answer was posted immediately after the question](http://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/784837/self-answered-questions-on-a-site) for  2.92% of all questions by 39 users for 0.4 % of all users.

The way I can tell that the poster answered immediately is that the Post.Id of the answer is exactly one more than that of the question.

To compare the [quality of the immediate self-answer to the averages for all questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/784840/self-answered-questions-on-a-site).

**Answer Score Average**

- Overall -> 7.17
- **Self -> 10.51**

**Question Score Average**

- Overall -> 10.34
- **Self -> 10.41**

**Average Number of Views**

- **Overall -> 2514.71**
- Self -> 2442.5

**Average Number of Favorites**

- Overall -> 1.94
- **Self -> 3.10**

**Average Number Answers**

- Overall -> 2.44
- Self -> 2.28

As you can see, the **only metric in which the self-answers are lower is that of views and the answers are on average significantly better.**

The number of answers attracted by a self-answer is lower, which is better because if someone writes a definite answer that covers all of the bases, then other people are much less likely to answer.

The other thing worth mentioning is the [type of users who immediately self answer.](http://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/784857/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions)

**Average Reputation**

- Overall -> 154
- **Self -> 7677.79**
- Percentage of Total -> 19.76

**Average Number of Votes Cast**

- Overall -> 12
- **Self -> 1284.90**
- Percentage of Total -> 42.04

**Average Number of Badges Gained**

- Overall -> 4
- **Self -> 94.38**
- Percentage of Total -> 14.79

I hope that I am making my points really clear here,

- Questions that are answered immediately after asking **are just as good** on average as questions that are not and **on average have better scoring answers**.
- The **users who invest** the time to write both the questions and answers are among the best and most involved on the site (0.4% of the users doing 42% of the voting) and **we should be encouraging them to keep posting**.
- If the self-answers weren't asking real questions, I think the community would have caught on by now, and if they were doing it out of selfishness, they probably wouldn't be as involved with the voting/flagging/editing as they are.

Comment: I also like the fact you self answered this :-)

Comment: Yeah, but, You can prove virtually anything using facts

Comment: Quibble: Too many insignificant digits!  Do some serious rounding!  Another fact I'd like to see:  Average number of answers for Overall and Self.  But, overall, a real contribution.

Comment: @ab2 Happy now?

Comment: :) ............

Comment: How are these statistics useful?  For you personally what did you find useful?